# Setting up behavior on a method appears to be calling the method

Tags: autofac, typemock

I posted this on the TypeMock forums, but am too impatient to wait for a response there.  This is a very n00b question.

I'm trying to set up a fake IContainer. Here's what I have:

```
var container = Isolate.Fake.Instance<IContainer>(); 
var program = Isolate.Fake.Instance<IProgram>(); 

Isolate.WhenCalled(() => container.Resolve<IProgram>()).WillReturn(program);
```

(`IProgram` is an interface in my code).

When I try to run this code, I get an Autofac exception: "The requested service MyApp.IProgram has not been registered."

How could this exception be thrown though? I'm not actually calling container.Resolve(), right? I'm just setting it up to return a fake IProgram.

Unrelated background info: I'm trialing TypeMock because Autofac uses extension methods extensively and Moq won't mock them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things that may help - first, you can mock `Resolve()` calls with Moq by setting up `IComponentContext.Resolve()`, which all of the extension methods delegate to.

Second, Autofac is designed so that you shouldn't have to use its interfaces from your components. See for examples:

- http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/the-relationship-zoo/
- http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/TypedNamedAndKeyedServices and
- http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories

Where you need to use (and thus mock) `IContainer` or a similar interface, you can probably do the same thing using the `Func`, `IIndex` and/or `Owned` relationship types.

Hope this helps!
Nick

Comment: Oh duh! I should have looked harder at my initial issue. Problem has been solved.  Thanks so much Nicholas!  I'm actually passing in a ContainerBuilder in one spot in my app, just to the bootstrapper and want to make sure it registers my modules correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's currently a bug in Isolator, which prevents faking Autofac containers. We're working to resolve it as soon as possible.

In the mean time, is there a reason you're not using Autofac as intended, meaning have it return a fake instance, such as:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestClass
{
    private ContainerBuilder builder;
    private IContainer container;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    }

    [Test, Isolated]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var fakeProgram = Isolate.Fake.Instance<IProgram>();

        builder.RegisterInstance(fakeProgram).As<IProgram>();
        container = builder.Build();

        var program = container.Resolve<IProgram>();

        Assert.AreEqual(fakeProgram, program);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer hmemcpy!  I would do this, but I'm actually faking the builder as well because it's a passed-in dependency to the bootstrapper.